# Generalised Eigen Vector may not correspond to an eigen value?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, solution-verification, generalized-eigenvector

Which of the following is/are true?

$(1)$ It is possible for a generalised eigen vector of a linear operator $T$ to correspond to a scalar that is not an eigen value of $T$.

$(2)$  Any linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space   has a Jordan Canonical Form.

$(3)$ A cycle of generalised eigen vector is linearly Independent.

$(4)$ There is exactly one cycle of generalised eigen vectors corresponding to each eigen value of a linear operator on a finite dimensional vector space.

My attempt :-

For $(1)$

I think it is **false**

It is enough to prove that if $x$ is a generalised eigen vector of $T$ corresponding to scalar $c$, then there is an eigen vector corresponding to $c$ which would imply $c$ must be an eigen value of $T$ (Right ? please correct me if I am wrong)

Proof :-

Let $x$ be a generalised eigen vector of rank $m$  corresponding to scalar $c$. Then

$(T-cI)^mx=0$ and $(T-cI)^{m-1}x\neq 0$

Let $u=(T-cI)^{m-1}x $ .

Then $u\neq 0$ and $(T-cI)u=0$.

Thus the result follows.

To my surprise, $(1)$ is given **True** in the answer. Don't know what's happening !

$(2)$ **False** since the characteristics polynomial has to split into linear factors.

$(3)$ **True**.

Proof :- Let a cycle of generalised eigen vector be

$\{x , (T-cI)x, (T-cI)^2x,..., (T-cI)^{m-1}x\}$

Let $U=T-cI$ and

$c_0x+ c_1Ux + c_2U^2x+...+c_{m-1}U^{m-1}x=0$ for some scalars $c_i$

Operating both sides by $U^{m-1}$, we get

$c_0U^{m-1} x=0$ since all other vectors are zero.

This gives $c_0=0$ since $U^{m-1}x\neq 0$

Proceeding similarly, $c_i=0 , \forall i$

So the set is LI

$(4)$ I don't really understand this option but as far as the wikipedia (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_eigenvector) article suggest there could be infinitely ways of choosing a generalised eigen vector of certain rank corresponding to an eigen value thus leading to different cycle of generalised eigen vector.

But again the answer is **True**.

Conclusion :- The answer given (true options) are $1,3,4$.

My main problem is in option $1$ and $4$.

Please help. Thanks for your time.

Comment: For (1) your answer is correct and hence the source is wrong. For (3) and (4): can you give the definition of 'cycle of a generalized eigenvector'? I never heard the term and the thing you list under (3) does not look particularly cyclic to me. Also in (2) is the field you are working over specified? Over $\mathbb{C}$ we the condition on the characteristic polynomial you mention is automatically satisfied

Comment: There was not as such a definition of "cycle of a generalized eigen vector"  given in the question set. Nor I had found any in my textbook. So I presumed that it as basis for the generalised eigen space corresponding to some eigen value  without giving a second thought (sorry for the ambiguity) . May be I thought so because there was a  strong resemblance between the basis of a generalised eigen space and the basis of a $T$ cyclic subspace generated by some vector. Otherwise I have no solid reason.